# Failed memory address

Tags: boot, bios, truecrypt

I'm getting the 'Non-system disk or disk error' message on an HP620 (circa 2011, dual core) after loading with Ubuntu.

Running the 'Startup Test' from the HP 'System Diagnostics' gives:

```
Failed memory address = 0xB10DA000
Pattern expected = 0xB97530ED
Pattern read = 0x30726670
```

What is going on here?  It feels like it could be part of the boot process. It is not the HD - I've tried a different, unused SSD as well.

Machine memory is fine - the Live CD runs okay.

(The original disk *did* have Truecrypt on it but the entire disk was wiped - and the second disk certainly didn't have it on.  Truecrypt wouldn't write to somewhere other than the HD would it? And if so, how would I put that right?)

Thanks for any advice you can give.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted.  Ubuntu was wrongly detecting a requirements for an EFI (UEFI) partition - UEFI on the HP620 is an 'unsupported' (according to a warning, but included) feature in the BIOS.

Looks like the HP620 was just on the cusp of UEFI coming into use.

The solution is to create two partitions manually ('Something else') as per [this page](https://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2020/05/step-by-step-to-install-ubuntu-2004.html), ignoring the EFI partitions. Ubuntu complains / warns about the boot arrangement in the installation but then boots fine once complete.